# Is it possible to update the intent used to create an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is it possible to modify an intent used to create an activity from inside that activity itself.

**Simple Description**
Is it possible to update the intent that is returned by

```
getIntent()
```

with new values and have it use those new values if an activity is recreated either due to the system killing it for resources, or orientation change, or when using developers options do not keep activities option is selected (which forces a recreate of an activity each time you leave it and come back to it).

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I am trying to achieve a way to pass variables(and update them) between activities without the use of a database or SharedPreferences. I want the data to only be alive when the app is, but also be easily recreatable by androids system prefs. 
It was just an idea I had, to try something new. I did not know that my explanation would be so hard to understand. Sorry about that.

**Complex Description**

**Scencario:**

From MainActivity I create another Activity (ActivityA) with below code

```
Intent tmp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
tmp.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startActivity(tmp);
```

Then in ActivityA print out that value

```
Log.i("TAG", getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key"));
```

the above line will print out Value in the log

Then in ActivityA i will press a button to start ActivityB with below code

```
Intent tmp = newIntent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
startActvityForResult(tmp, 1000) //1000 is the result code
```

Then when ActivityB starts when I press a button I want to send back data to ActivityA with below code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("Test1", "Value2");
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

All the above works with no problems. 
What I want to do is in ActivityA's onActivityResult(...)
modify the intent used to create ActivityA with the value returned here

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //modify intent used to create this activity with value received in data
}
```

So that when the activity gets recreated on orientation change OR (Developer option do not keep activity) when I leave the application the getIntent() function will return the new data (the one updated in onActivityResult(...)) and not the one that was used to originally create it (the call from MainActivity).

Is such a thing possible? I have been messing around with

```
setIntent(getIntent().putExtra("Key", "value obtained Intent data"))
```

but when the activity is recreated after going home the getIntent brings the first intent (the one used to create it originally) and not the modified intent that was created in onActivityResult(...)

Comment: It's probably just me, and a couple of beers, but my head is hurting trying to work out precisely what you're trying to *achieve*.  If it's not just me, you might want to try a more simple, reworded way of describing it.

Comment: @Simon I added a simple description. (hopefully). Its just alot of people always ask for more info about a problem so I decided to add the long description just in case.

Comment: well your question doesn't seem too clear to me, however in my understanding doesn't look like you are taking the right approach nor I belive is correct/possible. Have you tried using interfaces? on in the extreme case static variables?

Comment: I found it a bit confusing also. However, what you want isn't possible. Of course you will always get the original `Intent` from the previous `Activity`. If you want to save variables then you will need to use something like `SharedPrefs` or `DB` and save values say, in `onPause()`, `onBackPressed()` something like that depending on your needs.

Comment: It must be just me.  I'm completely confused by your simple description too.  Could you possibly explain what you are trying to `achieve`, instead of what you are tying to `do`?

Comment: I was planning on trying something different. I wanted to be able to pass an arraylist of values (purchased item sku's) that would have been created from a network call (using samsung IAP) and just have them move between activities. Doing so would have made it a bit harder to "hack" that you have purchased something you didn't without modifying the apk.

Comment: @codeMagic yea I wanted to try something new, if it was even possible. I didnt want to have the data persist in a perm storage.

Comment: @Simon I updated the post to show what I want to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to [store the activity's state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)? Also: from reading your comment about the IAP thing, what if the user restarts your app or the system? Shall he loose all purchased things in that case? I doubt that would make your customers happy.

Comment: No, it would check the purchases on its first run (splash page), then pass that info along between activities. The splash page would go check against a webserver then pass an array of all sku's purchased. But as stated by others it is not possible.

Comment: When I try to set anything in my Activity to Intent: getIntent().getExtras.putString(key,value); and check the update by getStringExtra(key), there is no update. So it is not possible, so use the bundle from outside, and change its state. Secondly, these updates happen in the UiThread or event only. Please try runOnUiThread and update in the runnable you provide.